# Increasing row limit import size

Tags: php, yii

Trying to import a file into my web application and it fails when importing >100k rows. Anything less is successful. File size is 14MB php.ini is set to 100MB file upload any ideas would be helpful.

PHP 5.4.20 (cli)
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.33-MariaDB

Comment: So how are you importing this file? And in what way does it fail?

Comment: importing via web interface. Just fails not sure which log file to check tbh for the error.

Comment: What web interface? We can't see what you're doing, what programs you might be using, what your web interface might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN php.ini check for `max_execution_time`   and eventually increase it